# How to return my merged array from merge() to sort()? Java merge sort algorithm

Tags: java, merge, mergesort

I am creating a merge sort for an assignment based on an interface I was given. (merge, mergesort, and sort). I am right there, but my brain is fried and I can't find the final issue with my code. I successfully merge the two as seen in the final "MERGE:" print, but then the final line "SORTEXAMPLE" goes back to being unsorted. I think it's an issue with my returns, but I can't wrap my head around it. Here is the code (I'm sorry it's all of it, the issue could be in any of the methods to my knowledge).

```java
@Override
public void sort(Comparable[] a) {
    if(a == null || a.length <= 1){
        return;
    }
    mergesort(a);
}

@Override
public Comparable[] mergesort(Comparable[] a) {
    int length = a.length;

    if(length <= 1){return a;} //base case

    int middle = length / 2;
    Comparable[] leftArray = new Comparable[middle];
    Comparable[] rightArray = new Comparable[length - middle];
    int l = 0, r = 0;

    for(; l < length; l++){     //copy contents to either left or right side
        if(l < middle){
            leftArray[l] = a[l];
        }
        else{
            rightArray[r] = a[l];
            r++;
        }
    }

    leftArray = mergesort(leftArray);       //sort left side
    rightArray = mergesort(rightArray);      //sort right side
    return merge(leftArray, rightArray);   //merge the two
}

@Override
public Comparable[] merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] b) {
    Comparable[] array = new Comparable[a.length + b.length];
    int arrayIndex = 0, aIndex = 0, bIndex = 0;

    while(aIndex < a.length && bIndex < b.length){
        if(less(a[aIndex], b[bIndex])){
            array[arrayIndex] = a[aIndex];
            aIndex++;
        }
        else{
            array[arrayIndex] = b[bIndex];
            bIndex++;
        }
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    while(aIndex < a.length){
        array[arrayIndex] = a[aIndex];
        arrayIndex++;
        aIndex++;
    }
    while(bIndex < b.length){
        array[arrayIndex] = b[bIndex];
        arrayIndex++;
        bIndex++;
    }
    System.out.print("MERGE: ");
    show(array);
    return array;
}
```

I am expecting the output to be "A E E L M O P R S T X" from an input of "SORTEXAMPLE" string array. It should function as a basic top down merge sort.

Comment: please provide an [mcve]

Comment: You do not assign the return value `a= mergesort(a);` instead of  `mergesort(a);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that your merge method is not updating the original array with the sorted result.

Instead, it is returning a new array array that contains the sorted elements.

Therefore, in your `mergesort(...)` method, when you call `merge(leftArray, rightArray)`, you are not actually updating the leftArray and rightArray arrays with the sorted result.

You can just make merge return `void` and update the original array a with the sorted result

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      a[i] = array[i];
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this is definitely what's throwing me off. While that's how I want to do it, and initially thought of solving the problem, I have to follow this interface for my assignment which returns Comparable [].